# Convert var to class object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api, get

I wish to get response from my ASP.NET web API which responds with an object type `Product`.

However when I try to get the response with Postman, it always return me with

> 500 Internal Server Error.

Below is my code, thanks in advance for any help offered:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
[Route("webapi/products/{productname}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProduct(string productname)
{
    var product = (Product)db.Products.Where(t => t.name.Contains(productname));
    //^^^^^^this seems to be the problem^^^^^^^//

    if (product == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(product);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where returns `IQueryable<Product>` (which means there might be more than one) and it can't be cast to Product.
If you want only one, then, you can take first from result:

```
var product = (Product)db.Products.Where(t => t.name.Contains(productname)).FirstOrDefault();
```

This can be simplified to:

```
var product = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(t => t.name.Contains(productname));
```

This will give you first of products that mach condition or null if none does.

Edit: As mentioned in comments, cast is not required here, but I'm leaving it in first example as to relate with original problem. Thanks, Nico.

Comment: thanks so much,I am so new to Linq, this was troubling me until I had to put them in List (that was the only way I know)

Comment: There is no reason to cast to `Product` the result of the `FirstOrDefault()` will be a type of `Product` and the compiler knows this.

Answer (score 0):

Where returns IEnumerable, you can't cast that to Product. If you want only the first matching value, you can call FirstOrDefault in the end like this:

```
var product = db.Products.Where(t => t.name.Contains(productname)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thanks so much for answering, however I could only accept one answer, @Shadowed was faster